# Change TIMESTAMP when execute update query

Tags: mysql, ddl

I try to update some values with an update query but have problems to create this table on reg_update:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
  id INT(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  product VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  reg_date TIMESTAMP,
  reg_update NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
)' at line 5
```

Is it posible to update in this case ***reg_update*** ?

Comment: data type of `reg_update` is missing before `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    CREATE TABLE Product (
      id INT(3) PRIMARY KEY,
      product VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      reg_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      reg_update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    );
```

Comment: I get this error: ERROR 1293 (HY000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

Comment: What is version of you mysql?